# Endpoint not being called when adding default parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have two endpoints:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Acc/{id:int}/Limit/{canIncreaseLimitsWithinSevenDays:bool}")]
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]Limit limit, bool canIncreaseLimitsWithinSevenDays = false)
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Acc/{id:int}/Limit")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
```

I get this error when calling the Put endpoint:

```
PUT:'Acc/1515749/Limit' MethodNotAllowed={
  "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."
```

This was working before I added the default parameter and both Routes were exactly the same.

How can I make it call the Put endpoint without having to specify the argument for the default parameter, and without having to change the Route of the Get endpoint?

Comment: Comment rather than answer as I'm not sure, but I think you need a ? on the route parameter. e.g. `[Route("Acc/{id:int}/Limit/{canIncreaseLimitsWithinSevenDays:bool?}")]` See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Comment: @AndyNichols, you are correct. he would need to make that parameter option by placing the question mark in the parameter placeholder of the route template.

Comment: That's it. Someone should write an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route parameter `canIncreaseLimitsWithinSevenDays` is required as it is not marked as optional. To mark it as optional it needs `?` (*question mark*) added to the parameter placeholder.

From [the Microsoft article on Web API attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional) it is explained as follows:

> You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.

meaning that you need to change your route attribute to

```
[Route("Acc/{id:int}/Limit/{canIncreaseLimitsWithinSevenDays:bool?}")]
```